# Separate newrelic application name for same rails environment

Tags: heroku, newrelic

I've set up NewRelic for a rails application on Heroku.
I notice NewRelic is determining the application name from the rails environment definition. This is mediated through the app_name variable in the newrelic.yml configuration file. However, I run the same rails environment on disparate Heroku applications, each being used for different development testing or staging purposes. So we entirely *do not* want all those applications (although using the same rails environment) to report back to the same NewRelic 'application'. That would provide no value at all in NewRelic - rather, each Heroku application should be its own 'application' in NewRelic, otherwise we just get one useless aggregate for all those applications each running a different source version of our application with different load or test simulations.

What should be the most straightforward and solid way to configure that separation?

Thanks!

*P.S. of course for our production environment we do want to have all dynos report back as one NewRelic application. Just not for disparate staging/test environments.*

Answer (score 6):

You could make a new environment variable for each of the disparate staging and test environments, and then pull that environment variable into your app_name in your newrelic.yml staging and testing environments.

For example, you could create an environment variable called SPECIFIC_APP and set it to "staging_one" for one of your apps and "staging_two" for another app, by running these commands in the respective apps:

`heroku config:set SPECIFIC_APP=staging_one`

`heroku config:set SPECIFIC_APP=staging_two`

Then, you could modify the New Relic app_name for each of those SPECIFIC_APP environments, like so:

```
staging:
  <<: *default_settings
  monitor_mode: true
  app_name: <%= ENV["NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME"] %> <%= ENV["SPECIFIC_APP"] %>
```

You could do the same thing for each of your testing apps, appending an additional app-specific environment variable to the "testing" environment at the end of your newrelic.yml.

This way, each application in the staging and testing RAILS_ENV's would be unique according to what the SPECIFIC_APP environment variable for each application is set to.